# Define a new operation and prove the field axiom hold for it.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Define $\ a\triangle b=ab$, where $a,b\in\Bbb R^{+}$, the set of positive real numbers. Show that $\exists x \in\Bbb R^{+}$ s.t $a\triangle x=0$.

I think the statement is false, because you can not find two positive number that their production is zero. Does anyone could help me to solve this question? Thanks!

Comment: why define a new symbol $\triangle$?

Comment: I don't know, it is a question from my instructor - -

Comment: are you sure it's the right definition? As it is, the point of it is somewhat vacuous.

Comment: Yes, I am sure --

Answer (score 2):

Consider the definition of zero-divisors given any commutative ring $(R, +, \circ, 0)$:

> $a \in R\setminus\{0\}$ is a zero divisor $:\Leftrightarrow \exists b\in R\setminus\{0\}: a\circ b = 0$.

As such a ring, $(\mathbb{R}, +, \circ, 0)$ is **zero divisor free**. So there isn't such an element, especially if you restrict the domain, since $\triangle$ is by definition just the multiplication restricted to a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I thinks so, thanks for your help.